# Unfortunately, (App Name) has stopped Android, Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I am able to compile, build, and install the project successfully And the project is running well in portrait, But In landscape mode, When I click in button, the app says: Unfortunately has stopped. Could you please help me figure this out?

This is The app Logcat In Landscape mode:

```
01-24 09:58:19.936: W/dalvikvm(6847): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at com.Divani.Marzieh.ExamActivity.addItemList(ExamActivity.java:79)
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at com.Divani.Marzieh.ExamActivity$1.onClick(ExamActivity.java:71)
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is The examActivity Code:

```
public class ExamActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText etInput1;
    private EditText etInput2;
    private Button btnAdd;
    private ListView lvItem;
    private ArrayList<Item> itemArrey;
    private ArrayAdapter<Item> itemAdapter;
    private static TabHost tabHost;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec1.setIndicator("LIST");

        TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
        spec2.setIndicator("DETAILS");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);

        tabHost.addTab(spec1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec2);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(id.tab1);

        setUpView();
    }
    public static TabHost getCurrentTabHost(){ 
        return tabHost; 
        }
    private void setUpView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        etInput1 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        etInput2 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.list);
        itemArrey = new ArrayList<Item>();
        itemArrey.clear();

        itemAdapter = new CustomlistActivity(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.textView1,itemArrey);
        lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                addItemList();
            }
        });
    }

      protected void addItemList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (isInputValid(etInput1) && isInputValid(etInput2)) {
            if(((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0)).isChecked())
                itemArrey.add(new Item(R.drawable.t,etInput1.getText().toString()+"\n"+etInput2.getText().toString()));
            else if(((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1)).isChecked())
                itemArrey.add(new Item(R.drawable.s,etInput1.getText().toString()+"\n"+etInput2.getText().toString()));
            else if(((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2)).isChecked())
                itemArrey.add(new Item(R.drawable.d,etInput1.getText().toString()+"\n"+etInput2.getText().toString()));
        itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ExamActivity.getCurrentTabHost().setCurrentTab(0);
        }
    }

    protected boolean isInputValid(EditText etInput2) {
        // TODO Auto-generatd method stub
        if (etInput2.getText().toString().trim().length()<1) {
            etInput2.setError("Please Enter Item");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater .inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
         EditText e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.item1:
             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ExamActivity.this, e.getText().toString(), 5000);
             toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
             toast.show();
             return true;
         default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: The two relevant lines of your log are: `01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at com.Divani.Marzieh.ExamActivity.addItemList(ExamActivity.java:79)` and `01-24 09:58:19.986: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at com.Divani.Marzieh.ExamActivity$1.onClick(ExamActivity.java:71)`. You should update your question adding some code, for example the snippet concerning those lines.

Comment: Which is the line 79 of you ExamActivity file?

Comment: eight seconds too late NKN

Comment: Why don't you try using the debugger?

Comment: The line of 79 is: if(((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0)).isChecked())

Comment: @NickT : I know that it's better I debug the app, but you know, I'm begginer in eclipse, So I need your guidance. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a separate layout main.xml for landscape, ie `layout/main.xml` and `layout-land/main.xml` ?  If so then check that `layout-land/main.xml` is not missing some or all of the radio buttons `radio0/1/2`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really help me :) I have .xml for landscape but the id of the radioGroups be wrong... Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

whenever you change the orientation of the screen the activity gets restarted after that the onStart() method is called.

Initialize your code that you are using at ExamActivity.addItemList(ExamActivity.java:79) in your onStart() method ex: your list or array

go through the site http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLifeCycle/article.html#configurationchange

Comment: Just to add to this answer for future readers: on orientation change the activity is actually destroyed and recreated; this means onCreate will get called again when transitioning to landscape.

So in the OP's source code, the activity is doing the right thing by calling setUpView from onCreate.